# Chamar stored procedure no laravel usando SQL Server com OUTPUT

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando chamar uma stored procedure pelo Laravel 5.5 mas não estou conseguindo. Estou usando o SQL Server.

Segue a stored procedure:

```
declare @CodigoRet int

exec Generator 'LancaContaContabil', @Codigo = @CodigoRet output

Select @CodigoRet
```

Pesquisei bastante e primeiramente tentei pelo jeito mais simples:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('DECLARE @CodigoRet INT; execute Generator 
\'LancaContaContabil\', @Codigo = @CodigoRet OUTPUT;'));
echo $results;
```

O código acima dá o seguinte erro: "The active result for the query contains no fields".

Tentei também com o statement, mas ele só retorna 1, segue abaixo:

```
$results = DB::statement('DECLARE @CodigoRet INT; EXEC Generator 
\'LancaContaContabil\', @Codigo = @CodigoRet OUTPUT;');
echo $results;
die;
```

Tentei também criando a procedure e chamando ela, mas dá o mesmo problema ("The active result for the query contains no fields"), como se não tivesse nenhum dado retornando do select:

```
$results = DB::select('EXECUTE testeproc');
echo $results;
die;
```

Estou fazendo algo errado ou existe um meio mais fácil de chamar essa stored procedure no laravel?

Comment: Você tem a StoredProcedure ai certinho?

Answer (score -1):

Acabei conseguindo resolver. Vou deixar aqui a solução que pode ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

```
$dbh = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC ProcLancaContaContabil");
$sth->execute();
$codigo = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

O truque mesmo foi colocar o "SET NOCOUNT ON" antes de chamar a procedure.

Achei ele [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql)